# How to get search results to scroll the top of the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, search, scroll, tableview

Previously my search results were showed clipped and I had to scroll up to down to see the full results

Where I want the Results to jump to the top of the tableview as soon as I start typing something in my search bar.

the code im using to make it work, works the first time but then I get the ***SIGABRT*** error in the AppDelegate as soon as I type in a new search.

```
productListTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

▲ there's the code that used to make the search results show at the top of the tableview but as soon as I type something new the simulator closes out on me. im trying to get hate results presented to the top everytime I punch in a new search

```
extension ProductListController : UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            productInventory = self.productSetup.filter({ (products) -> Bool in
                return products.name.range(of: searchText, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil 
                })

        self.productListTableView.reloadData()

      // Code that scrolls search results to the top of the tableview ▼

        self.productListTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

I've tried using the following from stack to help already but no luck

[UITableView - scroll to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724892/uitableview-scroll-to-the-top)

[How to get a UITableview to go to the top of page on reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542680/how-to-get-a-uitableview-to-go-to-the-top-of-page-on-reload)

[How to refresh my UITableView with UISearchBar after click of cancel button of UISearchBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427810/how-to-refresh-my-uitableview-with-uisearchbar-after-click-of-cancel-button-of-u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, before scrolling to row (0,0) you need to check that it exists:

```swift
if !self.productInventory.isEmpty {
    self.productListTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

second, `reloadData()` may not happen immediately - it may happen on the next run loop. So you should wrap the scroll in a dispatch block:

```swift
DispathQueue.main.async {
    if !self.productInventory.isEmpty {
        self.productListTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
     }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know where to put the second option but the first option worked perfectly